# Insert 1 milion record oracle sql where timestamp change

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, partitioning, bulkinsert

I need something like this

```
BEGIN
FOR v_LoopCounter IN 1..1000000 LOOP
        INSERT INTO "SVIL_FABRICKPSD2"."FBK_PAGOPA_TR_PAYMENT" (PAY_PAYMENT_ID, PAY_OWNER_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, PAY_DOCUMENT_ID, PAY_IUV_CODE, PAY_AUX_DIGIT, PAY_APPLICATION_CODE, PAY_DOCUMENT_AMOUNT, PAY_MAIN_CREDITOR_VIRTUAL_ID, PAY_HAS_SUB_CREDITORS, PAY_EXECUTION_DATETIME, PAY_PAYMENT_TOKEN, PAY_DESCRIPTION, PAY_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME_MS, PAY_IDEMPOTENCY_KEY, PAY_MODEL, PAY_STATUS, PAY_TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT_ID, PAY_CREATED_DATETIME, PAY_HAS_SENT_OUTCOME_NOTIFICATION, PAY_RETRY_COUNT) 
VALUES (v_LoopCounter, '3736', '302002011111111115', '02002011111111115', '3', '02', '0.03', '1', '1', TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-05-10 16:32:33.353820500 EUROPE/BERLIN', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(v_LoopCounter, 'DAY'), 'f49d7add8dec4988817a91065a052d05', 'TARI 2021', '1800000', '70000000007_100149bdWO', 'STARTED_FROM_PSP', 'CREATED', '9fb6ce76-86ce-4f9a-ad0b-151736d82a7a', TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-05-10 16:33:01.945286000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(v_LoopCounter, 'DAY'), '0', '0');
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

That will actually finish in like 5-10 minutes... I need to test the difference in cost with partitioning and without it with an interval of 1 day (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'day')) but I don't really know how to insert 1 milion record (where the insert date actually change each insert) in a small amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use loops, instead do it in a single statement as it will write (much) less to the log files:

```sql
INSERT INTO "SVIL_FABRICKPSD2"."FBK_PAGOPA_TR_PAYMENT" (
  PAY_PAYMENT_ID, PAY_OWNER_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, PAY_DOCUMENT_ID,
  PAY_IUV_CODE, PAY_AUX_DIGIT, PAY_APPLICATION_CODE,
  PAY_DOCUMENT_AMOUNT, PAY_MAIN_CREDITOR_VIRTUAL_ID, PAY_HAS_SUB_CREDITORS,
  PAY_EXECUTION_DATETIME, PAY_PAYMENT_TOKEN, PAY_DESCRIPTION,
  PAY_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME_MS, PAY_IDEMPOTENCY_KEY, PAY_MODEL,
  PAY_STATUS, PAY_TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT_ID, PAY_CREATED_DATETIME,
  PAY_HAS_SENT_OUTCOME_NOTIFICATION, PAY_RETRY_COUNT
) 
SELECT LEVEL, '3736', '302002011111111115',
       '02002011111111115', '3', '02',
       '0.03', '1', '1',
       TIMESTAMP '2023-05-10 16:32:33.353820500 EUROPE/BERLIN' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(LEVEL, 'DAY'),
       'f49d7add8dec4988817a91065a052d05', 'TARI 2021',
       '1800000', '70000000007_100149bdWO', 'STARTED_FROM_PSP',
       'CREATED', '9fb6ce76-86ce-4f9a-ad0b-151736d82a7a',
       TIMESTAMP '2023-05-10 16:33:01.945286000' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(LEVEL, 'DAY'),
       '0', '0'
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1e6;
```

Comment: I tried to add a number to LEVEL like select LEVEL+1000 but it slow down a lot, do you know if I can do anything to make it faster?

Comment: @LiefLayer Doing it all in a single query is as fast as you will get. Personally, I would be using a sequence to generate the ID column (rather then using `LEVEL`) and then you do not need to hardcode adding values.